# Why has my Google Analytics Goal stopped tracking visits?

Tags: google-analytics

I created a goal on Google Analytics which was working just fine all this time. It looked like this:

[image]

My URLs are dynamic so I chose the "Begins with". It was working fine until recently. I wanted to see full page URLs in my reports. So I created a filter to show the complete page URL following this link - https:// support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en

Since then, the goal won't track any visits. In the Goal funnel page, should I use the complete page URL now like **http:// sub.example.com/itineraryBooking** instead of **/itineraryBooking**?

**EDIT**

Here's how the new Goal details screen looks with the hostname included as part of the URL.

[image]

**EDIT after user nyuen's recommendation of using RegEx in Goal Details**

Please find the screenshot below. I have used RegEx while creating these steps but 3 of the 5 page links will be dynamic in nature. 2 links will be an exact match.

1. **Actual URL** -> http://pickyourtrail.com/itinerary/details/56e3f99b0956b30dd4eba428
2. **RegEx Step** -> .*veho.pickyourtrail.com/itinerary/details
3. **Actual URL** -> http://veho.pickyourtrail.com/itineraryCost?itineraryId=56e3f99b0956b30dd4eba428
4. **RegEx Step** -> .*veho.pickyourtrail.com/itineraryCost
5. **Actual URL** -> http://veho.pickyourtrail.com/itineraryBooking?itineraryId=56e3f99b0956b30dd4eba428
6. **RegEx Step** -> .*veho.pickyourtrail.com/itineraryBooking

Goal Step ->

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/filter-to-show-complete-url-path-in-google-analytics-reports/91564#91564), you had added a filter to include your hostnames, too. In this case you would need to adjust your goal URLs to include the hostname. So for example, step 1 would be ("begins with") `http://sub.example.com/search`, etc.

Comment: hey thanks for helping me out on this question as well. I suspected this could be the issue and had the hostname as part of the Goal details. Have Edited my question with a screenshot.

Since adding the hostname, I have waited for more than 24 hours but the Goal funnel is still empty. Nothing is getting tracked there. What am I missing? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you try using a regex instead for each step: `.*veho\.pickyourtrail\.com/search`, for example

Comment: Thanks. have edited my question with a screenshot by using RegEx. 2 out of 5 links are an exact URL match. Remaining 3 are dynamic  in nature. the query parameter on the URL will keep changing. Am not seeing any changes on the Goal Funnels yet. Appreciate the help!

Comment: For your regex, you would need to account for the dynamic parts, too, so you could use `.*` at the end, like `.*veho\.pickyourtrail\.com/itinerary/details.*`, and you will need to escape the `.`'s.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I added `.*` to the end of all three dynamic URLs. But it isn't working as when I Verify the goal, it only shows a 0.04% conversion rate which is not true.

Also, in order to group dynamic URLs in reporting, I had created a filter to exclude query parameters. Does this change everything we have been doing? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you explain how you think the 0.04% isn't true? As long as it's not 0, then that means the goal is converting (based only on last 7 days data). Also, if you want to exclude query parameters, you should do that through the settings ("Exclude URL Query Parameters")  rather than through a filter (only because it's simpler). Not sure how your filter was configured, so don't know if affects anything else.