# How to distinguish different subdomains in Google Analytics with Wordpress multisite?

Tags: google-analytics, domains, wordpress, subdomain, multi-subdomains

My current setup of Wordpress is multisite. (main site and a subdomain)

```
www.example.com/
blog.example.com/
```

I have also set up Google Analytics (same tracking code) for both of these sites.

The problem is that Google Analytics doesn't recognize that they are not the same site. (e.g. Google Analytics can't distinguish to which  site the root path `/` belongs to)

How to configure Google Analytics to distinguish between main site and the subdomain? Is it possible with just one tracking code?

My other configuration is Wordpress with Monster Insights plugin to handle analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest creating a filter to one of your reporting or testing views following this procedure https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en

This will record the full URL in your reports like domail.com or sub.domain.com.

There is a similar Q&A [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/filter-to-show-complete-url-path-in-google-analytics-reports).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like the answer I was looking for, have to test it on a live site.

Comment: @PeterGerhat how did you go? Have you found your answer?

Comment: Similar way as described here, I used Google Tag Manager to include additional fields (my website uses also anchors) and finally created a filter to put all things together.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually quite simple: you can use the `Hostname` as a secondary dimension in your reports to separate between the main site and the subdomain.

Alternatively, if you want a more permanent solution, you can set up a separate view for the subdomain as well. That process is described here: http://www.verticalrail.com/kb/filter-in-google-analytics-to-track-subdomains/